# Graph whose smallest edge clique cover is not the collection of all maximal cliques

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be an undirected simple graph. An *edge clique cover* of $G$ is a collection $\mathcal{C}$ of cliques (i.e., complete subgraphs) that cover all the edges of $G$. In other words, every edge belongs to at least one clique $C \in \mathcal{C}$. The smallest such collection of cliques $\mathcal{C}$ is sometimes known as the [intersection number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_number_(graph_theory)) of $G$.

Clearly, we can take $\mathcal{C}$ to be the collection of all maximal cliques of $G$. This can also be optimal, i.e., there is no smaller $\mathcal{C}$ which is also an edge clique cover.

But is there an example of a graph such that its smallest edge clique cover is different from the collection of all maximal cliques? As a bonus question, do we know exactly when the collection of all maximal cliques is an optimal collection in terms of the number of elements in $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: The bonus question part still remains, but I suspect this might be much more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the octahedron. All $8$ triangular faces are maximal cliques, however only $4$ of them is enough for an edge clique cover.

Comment: Yes, perfect. That is indeed a valid counterexample, thank you!